# Determine width of an element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an element that I need to move into the screen when a button is clicked, and then back off the screen when clicking again.

The problem is that I would like to not write a specific width of the box because it is not always going to be the same. I thought that this code should do it, but I'm getting a ReferenceError saying "Can't find variable: width". Any ideas how to improve it?

```
var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css(width);

console.log($("#about_box").width());

var itemOut = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#about").click(function(){

        var value1 = 30;
        var value2 = -itemWidth;

        console.log(itemOut);

        if (itemOut == false) {
            $("#about_box").stop();
            $("#about_box").animate({left: value1}, 350);
            itemOut= true;
        } else {
            $("#about_box").stop()
            $("#about_box").animate({left: value2}, 150);
            itemOut = false;
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: What is the `width` value you pass in parameter for this line ? `var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css(width);`

Comment: why are these lines different? var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css(width);

console.log($("#about_box").width());

Comment: Why are your first three lines of code outside the document ready call?

Comment: Your first line is causing the problem. css(width) does not exist. use width() instead, like your second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of these options:

```
$("#about_box").width() //element only width
$("#about_box").innerWidth() //element + padding width
$("#about_box").outerWidth() //element + padding + border width
```

And use it inside the $(document).ready handler, since before that you probably won't get any width as the DOM is not rendered yet.

Comment: Perfect, using .outerWidth and moving it inside $(document).ready did the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the Quotes here

`var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css(width);`

should be

`var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css("width");`

Answer (score 0):

This line has a syntax error and throw the exception : `var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css(width);`

You need to use :

`var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css('width');`

or

`var itemWidth = $("#about_box").width();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css(width);
```

change to:
var itemWidth = $("#about_box").width();
and consider if you need outer width (padding) or not.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var itemWidth = $("#about_box").css("width");
```

i.e. width in quotes.